# What metal (or any other material) is a good thermal conductor but a bad conductor of electricity?

Tags: material-science, conductors, thermal-conductivity

Also, this material needs to be easily manageable and accessible.

So, I am trying to make a DIY soldering iron and I need to insulate the part that makes the heat and the part that transfers the heat on its head. The part that makes the heat would be a very thin copper wire wrapped around the part that transfers the heat. But the two materials cannot touch each other otherwise the electricity from the copper wire will just flow through the other part and so no heat will be produced. So I need something that electricity would not flow through but heat would...
Thanks in advance,
Ray.

Comment: Diamond, but that might be a bit pricey...

Comment: Pure silicon is a marvelous conductor of heat and crappy with electricity. Not as good as diamond, but watch your fingers when working with it! Aluminum oxide is a much better mechanical material, though, silicon is very brittle. In practice you would use a cheap heat resistant engineering ceramic. Having said this, copper wire is a bad choice for a heating element to begin with and... _never_ make something that you can buy, _ever_. It's a waste of time, unless you want to start a business in the soldering iron market (yeah, that, for sure, is a waste of time).

Comment: As @CuriousOne points out, alumina is very good, thermal conductivity similar to aluminum and an excellent electrical insulator.  In the form of sapphire (industrial, not gem) it is transparent into the ultraviolet.

Comment: BeO (beryllia) is good too. Quite expensive and hard to deposit, I imagine.

Comment: @Gert: It's also highly toxic when inhaled. You need to be extremely careful with it when machining. I wouldn't touch that stuff, at all.

Comment: Tabulated here with a use for such compounds https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_grease

Answer (score 1):

Diamond is a excellent conductor of heat (heat conductivity five times higher than copper!) while being a very good electrical insulator. Of course its cost is prohibitive except for small parts made of industrial diamond.

Silicon emulates diamond's properties somewhat (its crystalline and atomic bonding structure is analogous to diamond) by being quite a good heat conductor while being a semi-conductor. Highly poor silicon ('chip' or 'solar' grades) is a very poor conductor of electricity and cheaply available.

**For comparative purposes:**

Heat conductivity of diamond: $k=220\:\mathrm{Wm^{-1}K^{-1}}$

Heat conductivity of silicon: $k=149\:\mathrm{Wm^{-1}K^{-1}}$

Comment: You may want to add the price comparison, too. Although, for plasma deposited diamond layers it may be OK. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne: I did mention diamond is far more expensive.

Comment: I'll assume you meant 'pure' not 'poor'. But, with a much smaller band gap, the conductivity (electrical) will increase with temperature fairly quickly, even for nominally intrinsic silicon.

Comment: It wasn't meant as a criticism, it's just fun to point out that diamond is usually not on the list of technically useful materials. I saw one case in my life in which a grad student was considering using a diamond ingot... until he saw the price tag. :-)

Comment: Diamond's thermal conductivity is given usually as 2000 W/(m K). Is supposed to be higher than the conductivity of copper which is about 400 in the same units

Answer (score 0):

Mica or fiberglass matting works well